# How to I access a pinia store variable by name (&and get a ref)

Tags: pinia

I need to build an "inspector" for a particular Pinia store containing runtime settings (persisted to server so things follow the user and reloads nicely)

I have a static map that hardcodes how each named property in the state should be visualized (name, friendlyName, min, max, comments, help texts etc) - and I need to correlate the name property with the name of the property in the store.

I can iterate the property of the  store.$state and get a nice array of properties, however it can't find a way get a ref by name from the store (this feels like reflection in C# - just need the last little step)

It feels like the the storeToRefs(store) need a storeToRefs(store, name:string) to get a ref by name in runtime.

Am I stepping out of bounds here or have I overlooked something in Pinia?